# SonarLint - exclude directo

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

We have SONAR QUBE running in a server. Now, we are trying to use SONAR lint plugin in IntelliJ to run the scan in local. We have enabled binding to remote Sonar Qube Server.

It produces scan results in local but we are not able to exclude the directories that we don't want sonar lint to scan.

Answer (score 2):

Excluding files or directories is not supported by SonarLint yet.

However, it is planned to be implemented in the upcoming weeks: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-801